# jenkins job description table with border

Tags: jenkins

I have two instances of Jenkins. Old (2.315) and new (2.315).

In a job's description I use HTML and table with border.

I see the a border on an old instance but not on a new one.

I checked everything I could but cannot find the problem.

Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Make sure your **Markup Formatter** config (under **Manage Jenkins** => **Configure Global Security**) is set to *Safe HTML*

Comment: It is. Otherwise I would not see the HTML table at all.

Answer (score 0):

Table border property is removed by Jenkins safeHtml

**Workaround** - use inline css like this [image: Example Table Border in Jenkins Job Description]